# Retrieving data to HTML table from SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I'm trying to get data to html table from database. In the database there's a company table which consists of id, name and percentage columns.

The above data in the table is entered by me manually. I need to fill those the same values by retrieving from database.

And company table in the database looks like this.[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFsmx.png)

In my coding it's getting an error in the place of array formation. I tried to get all the names in to one array and print in the html table. I'm kindly requesting to have a look at my coding. Highly appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, percentage FROM company";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $arr=str_split($row)

       //echo  $row;
       echo "<table> <tr> <td> $arr[1] </td> </tr> </table> ";

    }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
```

@jakumi Error is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxSbJ.png). Line 18 is '$arr=str_split($row);'.

Comment: and which error would that be?

Comment: add `;` in this line `$arr=str_split($row)`

Comment: @Jakumi I edited the question. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_split` expects a string, `$row` however already is an array. you access fields of each row by just `$row['name']` for example.

so

```
echo '<table>';
while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$arr['name'].'</td><td>'.$arr['percentage'].'</td></tr>'; 
}
echo '</table>';
```

**updated for answering a specific comment:**

```
$percentages = [];
$namesToPercentages = [];
$collection = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $percentages[] = $row['percentage']; 
    // this produces [0 => 0, 1=>1.1, 2=>1.2, ...]

    $namesToPercentages[$row['name']] = $row['percentage'];
    // this produces ['Base_price' => 0, 'A' => 1.1, ...]

    $collection[]= $row;
    // this produces [['name' => 'Base_price', 'percentage'=>0], [...],...]
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jakumi what I need to do is retrieve the names in database table to html table rows as I mentioned in the above image. If I use $row['name'] it will print all the names at once. There's no way to split them by name by name. That's why I planned to create a array. Do you any solution to do this? Thanks!

Comment: for your query it should not post all the names at once

Comment: You're a Legend. It's working. You helped me last time too. Thanks heaps. God bless you champ @Jakumi!

Comment: @RyanOscar don't know how you want your array to be structured, provided some cases in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi <3